# Extract password settings from Thunderbird accounts

Tags: passwords, thunderbird

Let's say I have installed Thunderbird on Windows 7 and it stopped booting, but I have Ubuntu installed as dual-boot system and now still have read-access to the Windows drive.

Can I easily read the passwords for my old mail accounts stored in Thunderbird from Ubuntu to re-enter them into the new installation? No master-password was used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this site, it might something you can do to get your mail back: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/diy-back-up-and-migrate-a-thunderbird-profile-and-folders/

Also, have a look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=203524 
This talks about sharing your Thunderbird account across multiple OS's (through Dual Boot).  You might be able to just copy over your profile(s) to Ubuntu and go from there.  Otherwise, as you say you have read-access to the Windows drive, you can just leave them where they are and continue as you were.

HTH

Comment: Not really what I wanted, but even better as workaround! Thanks

Comment: Glad it's of some use at least.  If I come across anything online that would be better, I shall drop it here for you :)
Have a good day